# Get method for maps in groovy

Tags: grails, config

In Config.groovy:

```
Query {
    parameterMap {
        time.'1328' =  ['T1']
        time.'1329' =  ['T2']
        templates.'T1'   =  ['X','Y','Z']
        templates.'T2'   =  ['Z']
    }
}
```

In QuartzSchedulerJob I want to use `T1` and `T2` which are `templateId` as key to get the corresponding values in `parameterMap` but it returns me `null` and `[:]` respectively, `parameterMap.templates.get("${v}")` but I want to get `['X','Y','Z']` and `['Z']` respectively for `T1` and `T2`

```
def execute() {
    def currentTime = new Date().format('HHmm')
    grailsApplication.config.Query.parameterMap.time.each { k, v ->
        if (currentTime=="${k}") {
            println "${k} " + currentTime
            String templateId = "${v}".replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","")
            println grailsApplication.config.Query.parameterMap.templates.get("${v}") //this prints null
            println grailsApplication.config.Query.parameterMap.templates.getAt("${v}") //this prints [:]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `v` is a list. You need the first element of `v`, is `v[0]`. Also, not sure what you're doing, but this feels like a horribly complex way to go about it

Answer (score 1):

`"${k}"` is a weird expression, and I see it a lot in Groovy code. I would love to know who and/or what (book/blog/???) somehow got people using that syntax. I see it quite often in `toString` methods that intend to return a class field as the value, e.g.

```
private String name
...
String toString() {
   "${name}"
}
```

Why not just return the variable?

```
String toString() {
   name
}
```

You're doing this here, making a `GString` `"${k}"` with only a single embedded variable and no other characters, and then implicitly converting it to a String when comparing it to `currentTime` (which works, but is far from optimal or sensible) and using this `GString` to generate (in a very funky way) to a potential key in a `Map` when calling `get` and `getAt`, and wondering why the value inside this weird little `GString`, which is very close to being a map key (as Tim points out the values of the `time` map are single-element `List`s, and the keys of the `templates` map are `String`s which are the single elements of these `List`s) isn't also automagically converted into what you wanted it to have been.

Groovy does lots of implicit conversions, but the signature of the `get` method in `Map` is `Object get(Object key)` (technically it's got a generic return type, but that's not relevant here) so Groovy isn't going to do any conversion for you - you're passing an `Object` as a parameter to a method that takes `Object`. There's no reason at all to expect that it would be converted to a String, or to any of the types of any of the keys, or to anything at all.

This loc hurts my brain:

```
String templateId = "${v}".replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","")
```

You're taking the list `v`, converting it to a `String` by embedding it with nothing else in a `GString`, coercing Groovy to convert the `GString` to a `String` so it can call `replaceAll` on it, to remove the brackets that are at the beginning and end of the `toString` form of `AbstractCollection`, to extract the single `String` element in `v`.

How about something a bit more direct:

```
String templateId = v[0]
```

and its use in a cleaned up version of `execute`:

```
def execute() {
    String currentTime = new Date().format('HHmm')
    grailsApplication.config.Query.parameterMap.time.each { k, v ->
        if (currentTime == k) {
            println "$k $currentTime"
            String templateId = v[0]
            println config.Query.parameterMap.templates[templateId] // get and getAt would also work
        }
    }
}
```