# Dynamically scheduling jobs: using cron trigger in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I am still playing around with quartz scheduler.I created the below job using
grails create-job ,what i am trying to do here is simple, that is create a
trigger and  try to run the execute method.once this basic code runs i want to
create multiple triggers each with different cron schedule value, inside a for
loop(multiple triggers with different execution time) and run the execute
method and do `sched.scheduleJob(triggerName)` over list of these triggers

```
import org.quartz.*
import org.quartz.Trigger
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
public class TrialJob 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestJob.class).withIdentity("dummyJobName1","group11").build();

       CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger","group1").withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 55 15 * * ?")).build();

       Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

       scheduler.scheduleJob(job,trigger);

       scheduler.start();

       //while(true){};
    }    

    public static class TestJob implements Job 
    { 
       public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
       {
           println "inside execute "
       }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable example to allow other users to try.

Comment: hi opal i have updated my code still the execute method does not work ..i am pretty new to qaurtz scheduler so not pretty sure if the cron trigger is correct as well ?

Comment: What's the quartz's version?

Comment: version is Quartz Scheduler 2.2.1 ...i think the trigger is not working and execute method is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the code provided doesn't compile. There's an attempt of assigning instance of class `org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory` to a variable declared as `org.quartz.Scheduler`.

Secondly the program runs well and the job is scheduled but the it exists before any output is caught. To prove it run below example with uncommented `//while(true){};` line. The example is taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-2-scheduler-tutorial/).

```
@Grab(group='org.quartz-scheduler', module='quartz', version='2.2.1') 

import org.quartz.*;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class CronTriggerExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
        .withIdentity("dummyJobName1", "group11").build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName1", "group11")
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
        .build();


        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger); 

        //while(true){};
    }
}

public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");    
    }
}
```

Hope that helped you.

Comment: hi opal thanks a lot for the code ..but even in the above the code the execute method is not getting called as i don't see anything getting print..is this annotation required @Grab(group='org.quartz-scheduler', module='quartz', version='2.2.1')  ..i tried running the code with and without this ..i don't know where am i going wrong..

Comment: This is ready to run code in groovy console. To see the output uncomment line: `//while(true){};`.

Comment: You can also copy the code, save it to *whatever.groovy* and run with `groovy whatever.groovy`.

Comment: hey bro it is working now :) thanks a lot!! ...can i create multiple triggers inside a for loop with everytime a new withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?")) value for cronschedule ?

Comment: If it works please accept and upvote. This is different question. Post it.

Comment: hi opal i have posted my question on multiple triggers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893532/single-job-with-multiple-triggers-quartz-groovy  please let me know how i can resolve that error ..thanks a lot