# jobDataMap to pass parameters for Multiple Triggers in Quartz

Tags: groovy, quartz-scheduler

> Hi my code works with multiple triggers and i am trying to pass specific parameters associated with
>   each trigger using jobDataMap.But when i am trying to assign the map in my config.groovy to 
>   jobDataMap i get a nullpointerexception

```
**This is the Map in my Config.groovy-->**

Query
{
    Map
    {
        time.'0/5 * * * * ?' =  ['T1']
        time.'0/10 * * * * ?' =  ['T2']
        templates.'T1'   =  ['Date','FinshDate','Location']
        templates.'T2'   =  ['TableName']
        parameterValues.'T1'   =  ['2014071600','2014072000','Path']
        parameterValues.'T2'   =  ['AppleData']
    }
}   

**This is my Quartz Job Code for multiple triggers ->**

import org.quartz.*
import org.quartz.Trigger
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsApplication;
public class TrialJob 
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String JobName
       String GroupName
       GrailsApplication grailsApplication;
       Trigger trigger
       def triggerList=[]
       def jobList=[]

       def cronList=["0/5 * * * * ?","0/10 * * * * ?","0/15 * * * * ?"]

       // here i am creating 3 triggers which works fine
       for(i in 0..2)
       {

          JobName="trigger"+Integer.toString(i) 
          GroupName = "Group"+Integer.toString(i)
          println cronList[i]
          JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestJob.class).withIdentity(JobName,GroupName).build();
         trigger= TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(JobName,GroupName).withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronList[i])).build();
         triggerList.add(trigger)
         jobList.add(job)
      }

      Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
      scheduler.start();

      for(j in 0..2)
      {

       // here i want to put the associated parameters for each trigger in the trigger list 
       // For Example 1)  trigger 0--> triggerList[0].jobDataMap.put(['Date','FinshDate','Location'],['2014071600','2014072000','Path'])
       // 2) trigger 1--> triggerList[1].jobDataMap.put(['TableName'],['AppleData'])
       scheduler.scheduleJob(jobList[j],triggerList[j]);
       println "torpido"
       println j
      }

   //while(true){};
}    

    public static class TestJob implements Job 
    {  
       public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException 
       {
          HashMap<String, String> parameter  =  new HashMap();
          parameter=context.getMergedJobDataMap()
          println "Inside Execute"
       }        
    }
}
```

> how do i use jobDataMap inside the above for loop (it would be more
>   clear by looking at the comments inside the for loop) and access them
>   inside the execute method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not grails expert but it seems that grails quartz scheduler [plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quartz) should be used.

Below You can find working code:

```
@Grab(group='org.quartz-scheduler', module='quartz', version='2.2.1') 

import org.quartz.*;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class CronTriggerExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        def cronExpressions = ['0/5 * * * * ?', '0/10 * * * * ?', '0/20 * * * * ?']

        def triggers = cronExpressions.collect { cron ->
            TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger-$cron", "trigger-$cron-group")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cron))
                .usingJobData(new JobDataMap(['cron': cron]))
                .build()
        }

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler()
        scheduler.start()

        triggers.each { trigger ->
            def job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob).withIdentity("$trigger.key.name-job", "$trigger.key.name-job-group").build()
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
        }
        while(true){}
    }
}

public class HelloJob implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        println "Hello Quartz with cron: ${context.mergedJobDataMap.getString('cron')}"
    }
}
```

Job name, job group as well trigger name, trigger group must be unique. Other objects can be passed with `JobDataMap`. Is that clear now?

Comment: hi opal thanks a lot again :) i could get the multiple triggers fixed already  ..the main problem i face is with the jobDataMap to pass specific parameters to each trigger before scheduling them .Please have a look at the new code ..

Comment: You can say thanks with upvoting :) You can pass other objects with `usingJobData` when constructing a trigger - see the example I provided.

Comment: Or.. with the following piece of code: `triggerList[j].jobDataMap.put('params', ['some', 'list']`. see the API: http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/JobDataMap.html

Comment: Is that clear now? If so, please accept the answer or let me know how can I help You?

Comment: i tried something like this ...triggerList[j].jobDataMap.put('params',(['date','finishDate','location'],['2014071600','2014072000','path'])) but this is not working...how do i pass 2 lists as parameters

Comment: What is not working exactly? Put it as a list of lists: `[['date','finishDate','tableName'],['2‌​014071600','2014072000','appledata']]` and deconstruct in `Job` implementation.

Comment: but i am not able to access grailsApplication.config.Query.Map ..still gives java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
 at TrialJob.main  however it worked for a different application

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no grails knowledge. Please consider using the plugin I mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68691/discussion-between-elyon-and-opal).